# Selenium - Enter a text using java script

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

Insert a value in a particular element by using javascript

Html code

```
<div class="CodeMirror-code" style="">
<div style="position: relative;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: -52px;">
    <div class="CodeMirror-linenumber CodeMirror-gutter-elt" style="left: 18px; width: 12px;">1</div>
</div>
<pre>
    <span class="cm-word"></span>
</pre>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to insert a text in the span class `<span class="cm-word"></span>`

Code:

```
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='CodeMirror-code']//pre"))
JavascriptExecutor executor = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='sample text';", webElement)
```

When I execute the code value was not inserted and I'm not getting any error. Normal setText method not working, so that I choose the javascript option.

This is a salesforce application console mode execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `innerHTML` property instead:

```
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'sample text';", webElement)
```

Alternatives:

- textContent: `arguments[0].textContent = 'sample text'`
- innerText: `arguments[0].innerText = 'sample text'`

The `value` property is used for form fields that allow user input.